# spit audio(IN/OUT) in freepbx

Tags: asterisk, voip, audio-recording, ubuntu-16.04, freepbx

How to split the audio files from customer and caller in freepbx and mix them after? Like having 3 recordings in every call.

- freepbx- 12.0.76.4
- asterisk - 11.23
- ubuntu - 16.04 LTS
- recording file type: gsm

Answer (score 1):

By default asterisk record files in following format:

8kbit pcm 16 bit mono.

After mixmonitor in most sytem you have STEREO with left channel=incoming, right channel=outgoing.

You can split any one stereo channel to file using ANY tool for audio conversion,for example via SOX.

I can't say what will be in variant with gsm recoring, but you always can change recording to wav.

Comment: I  can change it to wav. But to split it can you help me how to do it?

Comment: I follow the link and use the commands  but did not split the calls. sox infile.wav outfile.l.wav remix 1. I can still hear the customer and the agent talking.

Comment: If your line is analog, you have ONE wire and sound is MIXED, so no way split. If you have only digital communiction it should work.

Comment: im using a voip to do the calls.Not sure if this is what you mean.